# How to convert template from table to div

Tags: php, css, html-table

I have tried in weeks to convert this template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<?php echo head();?> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body leftmargin="10" topmargin="10" marginwidth="10" marginheight="10" class="background"<?php echo onload();?>>
<a name="top"></a> 
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td><table class="main" align="center" width="755" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr> 
          <td class="header"colspan="2"><div class="sitetitle"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td valign="top" width="220"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr> 
                <td><table class="navigation" align="left" width="170" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr> 
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td valign="top"> <?php echo toc();?> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                  <td valign="top" class="menu"><p><?php echo sitemaplink();?></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td valign="top" class="menu"><p><?php echo printlink();?></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td valign="top" class="menu"><p><?php echo mailformlink();?></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td valign="top" class="menu"><p><?php echo guestbooklink();?></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td valign="top" class="menu"><p><?php echo languagemenu();?></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td valign="top" class="menu"><p><?php echo loginlink();?></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td valign="top" class="menu"><p><?php echo lastupdate();?></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td class="eckenaviunten"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr> 
                      <td class="searchbox"><?php echo searchbox();?></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          <td valign="top" width="550"> <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr> 
                <td><div class="locator"><?php echo locator();?></div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table align="center" width="550" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
              <tr> 
                <td class="eckeoben"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                <td class="content" valign="top"> <?php echo editmenu();?> <?php echo content();?> 
                  <?php echo submenu();?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                <td class="eckeunten"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td class="endline" colspan="2"><div align="center"><?php echo footer();?></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is:

```
.codeview {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}
BODY,TD{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size:8pt;
    color:#000000;
}
H1,H2,H3{
    font-size:13pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:6px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
H4{
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(images/infotable.png);
    border: 1px solid #003399;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #003399;
}

ul.menulevel1,ul.menulevel2,ul.menulevel3,ul.sitemaplevel1,ul.sitemaplevel2,ul.sitemaplevel3,ul.submenu,ul.search{padding-left: 0;margin-left: 0;list-style: none;}

form{margin:0;}
IMG{border:0;}

li{line-height:1.5;}

.doc{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu/doc.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.docs{padding-left:15px;background-image: url(menu/docs.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.sdoc{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu/sdoc.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.sdocs{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu/sdocs.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}

.sitemaplevel1 .doc{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/doc.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.sitemaplevel1 .docs{padding-left:15px;background-image: url(menu2/docs.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.sitemaplevel1 .sdoc{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/sdoc.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.sitemaplevel1 .sdocs{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/sdocs.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}

.submenu .doc{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/doc.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.submenu .docs{padding-left:15px;background-image: url(menu2/docs.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.submenu .sdoc{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/sdoc.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.submenu .sdocs{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/sdocs.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}

.search .doc{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/doc.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.search .docs{padding-left:15px;background-image: url(menu2/docs.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.search .sdoc{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/sdoc.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.search .sdocs{padding-left: 15px;background-image: url(menu2/sdocs.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;}

a{text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;}
a:link,a:visited{color:#1B366C;}
a:active,a:hover{color:#728DC3;}

.sitename{font-weight:normal;font-size:20pt;}

.menulevel1{font-size:8pt;color:#FCDE1C;}
.menulevel1 a{font-weight:normal;color:#FFFFFF;}
.menulevel1 a:link,.menulevel1 a:visited{color:#FFFFFF;}
.menulevel1 a:active,.menulevel1 a:hover{color:#FCDE1C;}
.sitemaplevel1,.sitemaplevel2,.sitemaplevel3{font-size:9pt;}
.sitemaplevel1 a,.sitemaplevel2 a,.sitemaplevel3 a{font-weight:normal;color:black;}
.sitemaplevel1 a:link,.sitemaplevel2 a:link,.sitemaplevel3 a:link,.sitemaplevel1 a:visited,.sitemaplevel2 a:visited,.sitemaplevel3 a:visited{color:black;}
.sitemaplevel1 a:active,.sitemaplevel2 a:active,.sitemaplevel3 a:active,.sitemaplevel1 a:hover,.sitemaplevel2 a:hover,.sitemaplevel3 a:hover{color:black;}
.submenu{
    font-size:8pt;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.submenu a{font-weight:normal;color:black;}
.submenu a:link,.submenu a:visited{color:black;}
.submenu a:active,.submenu a:hover{color:#1B366C;}
.search a{font-weight:normal;color:black;}
.search a:link,.search a:visited{color:black;}
.search a:active,.search a:hover{color:black;}
.locator{
    font-size:8pt;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    background-image: url(images/pageico.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: 20px;
    height: 19px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.locator a{font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline}
.locator a:link,.locator a:visited,.locator a:active,.locator a:hover{color:white;}
.menu{font-weight:normal;font-size:7pt;color:white;}
.menu a{
    color:white;
    font-size: 7pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu a:link,.menu a:visited,.menu a:active,.menu a:hover{color:white;}
.login{font-weight:bold;font-size:8pt;color:grey;}
.login a,.login a:link,.login a:visited,.login a:active,.login a:hover{color:gray;}
.navigator{font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt;color:white;}
.navigator a:link,.navigator a:visited{color:#c0c0c0;}
.navigator a:active,.navigator a:hover{color:white;}

.edit{
    font-size:8pt;
    color:black;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(images/edit.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.edit a:link,.edit a:visited,.edit a:active,.edit a:hover{font-weight:normal;color:black;}
input,select{font-size:8pt;}
textarea{font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica;font-size:8pt;background-color:white;width:98%;}
.searchbox .text,.searchbox .submit{border:2px solid #c0c0c0;background-color:white;}


.background {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(images/cmsimpledebg.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.main {
    background-image: url(images/center.png);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #103482;
}
.eckeoben {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(images/eckeoben.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    height: 17px;
}
.eckeunten {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(images/eckeunten.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    height: 17px;
}
.content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.eckenavioben {
    background-color: #3C5A99;
    background-image: url(images/eckenavioben.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 17px;
}
.eckenaviunten {
    background-color: #3C5A99;
    background-image: url(images/eckenaviunten.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 17px;
}
.navigation {
    background-color: #3C5A99;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-image: url(images/navigation.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.searchbox .text {
    border: 1px solid #D5DDED;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(images/textfield.png);
    text-indent: 2px;
}
.searchbox .submit {
    border: 1px solid #103482;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(images/submit.png);
}
.header {
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 180px;
}
.endline {
    background-color: #BAD5FF;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.sitetitle {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #008040;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 220px;
}
.borderheadline {
    background-image: url(images/boderheadline.png);
}
.infotable {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    background-image: url(images/infotable.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #003399;
}
.codeview {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.warning {
    color: #FF0000;
    background-image: url(images/ausrufezeichen.png);
    text-indent: 30px;
    height: 35px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Do you  know a good tutorial on how to convert it from table to div?

**Edit:**

The template and screenshot of it can be found at: http://www.cmsimple-styles.com/cmsimplestyles/en/?Templates:Template_Downloads__1. The temple is called "cmsimple de". It's a little down the page :)

Comment: If you could upload a screenshot somewhere of what the result should look like (or a link to the current table-based page), it will give everyone a better idea of how the page looks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to convert table layout to CSS layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696116/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-table-layout-to-css-layout)

Comment: possibly helpful: [Best tutorial on CSS 2.0 positioning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835115/best-tutorial-on-css-2-0-positioning)

Comment: possibly helpful: [Modern HTML tutorial](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69159/modern-html-tutorial)

Comment: I agree with @Pekka, there is no sure-fire way of converting a `<table>` to `<div>` layout. I'm sure quite a few people could build what you are after but you will miss the learning that goes with building it yourself. I would have a go and if you get stuck post a specific question here, otherwise if you take a solution here you might have more problems later if there are layout bugs (especially when it comes to cross-browser support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS display property could help here?

```
<table> --> #topdiv { display:table; }
<tr> --> .row { display:table-row; }
<td> --> .cell { display:table-cell; }
```

It probably isn't the best way - is still is table design - but it should work reliably and all from css. (Never tried this personally, so not sure what other properties you'll need to set.)

Comment: It may be a good idea, but I am thinking about getting rid of every table tag. Sorry, maybe I do not fully understand your answer. Uhm..

Comment: Yeah, replace the table tag with a div of id topdiv; replace the tr tags with divs of class row; replace the td tags with divs of class cell.

It _should_ look like your table as before, but all css based - if that is what you desire.

Comment: Haha sorry got that backwards (been ages since I table styled) - meant row not column.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will take a look on it when I had slept. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

replace 'table' 'tr' 'td' with div

set tr's width the same with table's width

Comment: Okay, thanks. And for the css. Some places in the html code, there's things like "colspan" and "cellpadding". What about those? I don't think they can be used in div tags...

Comment: cellpadging use css padding.
 
colspan you can edit width to fit this.